# Get-SPUser: Error cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I'm trying to display first name  last names instead of DOMAIN\username.
I tried running :

```
Get-SPUser –Web webapplication| Set-SPUser –SyncFromAD
```

But i keep getting the rror :

cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user domain\username.

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Also when i click on manage user profiles its blank but shows total numbers of profile 4.

Thanks in Advance

** Also I  notice the errors shows it can't find all the "Farm Administrators accts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin by checking the User Profile Service. You say that the page is blank. That is normal, you have to enter a filter string. I suggest you use your domain name, that will return all the profiles. If those profiles have first and last (I suspect they do not) then you need to run a synchronization. After that is complete SharePoint will sync with the web applications.

Matthew

Comment: Thanks Matthew.Tried all parameters but returned nothing.
I would delete the UPS and start again or maybe even won't use it.